# How do enemy health, armour and shields scale with level?

Tags: warframe

Enemies get more powerful as their level increases: the same weapon can kill a level 1 Grineer in one hit, but a level 30 one can survive a magdump at point blank.

How do these things scale, and exactly how much tougher are higher-level enemies?

Answer (score 2):

Look at that, I think you gonna find what you're looking for : [Enemy Level Scaling Warframe](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_Level_Scaling)

In this article, you can find a lot of graphs that show you how enemy stats scale (health, health+armor...), how your affinity scale, and also the hitpoints and their effectiveness on enemies. Graphs are a bit tough to understand, but the text helps you a lot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks like a great resource, but would you mind summarizing the content from the link to prevent link rot? Thanks!

Comment: @Momop. Two Bugs is trying to tell you that you should post the actual information here, in your answer. This is to prevent you from just posting a link, which may not be permanent. If someone were to find this question 5 years from now, and that link was dead, then your answer is useless.